# The problem when i proved \$3S_Y=S_\Delta\$ by using \$S=I^2 Z\$ in three phase circuit

Tags: power, three-phase

There is the proof about \$3S_Y=S_\Delta\$ in lots of books
[image]

I have other way to prove the \$3S_Y=S_\Delta\$,however,there is a problem in my proof,but i don't know where am i wrong

As we can see the proof as above,we can know that proof is using the \$S=\frac{V^2}{Z}\$ to prove \$3S_Y=S_\Delta\$

However,as we know \$S=\frac{V^2}{Z}=I^2 Z\$,that is ,we can use \$S=I^2 Z\$ to prove \$3S_Y=S_\Delta\$  ,too!

**Here is my proof by using \$S=I^2 Z\$**

[image]

Now i have \$S_Y=3S_\Delta\$ ,but the answer should be  \$3S_Y=S_\Delta\$,where am i wrong by using this method(\$S=I^2 Z\$)?

Comment: Your dropping the square on your VL’s.

Comment: @relayman357 what do you mean??

Comment: When you square (VL/root3) you should get a VL^2 term.

Comment: @relayman357 OH i know it,that is a small problem,but my problem is not that,by the way,i have improved the first figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phase current in the star configuration `(with Z/3)` converted from delta `(with Z)` is wrong-

[image]

The phase current in the star configuration `(with Z/3)` converted from delta `(with Z)`will be

$$I'_{p} = \frac{V_{L}\sqrt{3}}{Z}$$

$$I'_{p} = 3I_{p}$$

which gives you 
$$S^{\Delta} = 9I^{2}_{p}Z$$

and 
$$S^{Y} = 3I^{2}_{p}Z$$

hence

$$3S^{Y} = S^{\Delta}$$

Answer (score 0):

> *there is a problem in my proof,but i don't know where am i wrong*

This seems an obvious mistake: -

[image]

Comment: oh yes,but my problem is not that ,my proof is using P=I^2R,But get the wrong solution,the mistake you said  is just a small and obvious mistake

Comment: You asked if there *is a problem in my proof* and I have shown 1 and cannot rule out more. Why have you corrected your error in the question? It now makes my answer look faulty and I don't want people to come along and downvote because of that. If you are making a correction in your question that then counteracts an already given answer \$\color{red}{\text{YOU SHOULD MAKE THAT CLEAR}}\$ when you amend your question.

Comment: my proof is in the second figure,the first figure is the proof in my book,i just make that mistake with careless,divyam have answered what i really want to ask

Comment: well i have already said that which is the proof from the book,which part is my proof in the begining,i think you didn't understand that first,However,indeed i make a mistake in my first figure,thanks for your reminding

Comment: @Andyaka shouting?